# how soon after unprotected sex can side effects of getting pregnant occur?

Tags: obstetrics

a person, lets call him bob had unprotected sex with jane on friday night lets say saturday morning at like 4 am. Monday evening at around 11 pm the girl feels like throwing up and bad generally.

Can it be because she is pregnant?

Comment: TL;DR - no, that's not a sign of being pregnant. Throwing up arrives in MUCH later stage. If anything, it might be result of the stress from the possibility of pregnancy.

Comment: that is not really what the link you posted said though... basically they said "each person is different"

Comment: Close enough in my opinion. Ideally, the answer here should be posted in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

If fertilization took place, chances are that implantation wouldn't even have happened yet, since that takes 3-4days, so until that happens, your body has no clue *anything* happened, much less react to it. http://www.webmd.com/baby/understanding-conception#1

Comment: hmm but if you count, saturday, sunday, monday... it can add up to 3 days actually

Comment: Well at that point it's not something that gives you symptoms.  You cannot feel different the moment that implantation happens.  That is not something you can *feel* or experience.   You feel sick only *after* your hormones change.  That doesn't happen at the moment of implantation.